# Rendering SVG PATH element on JavaFX WebView onclick event not triggered

Tags: svg, javafx, inkscape, javafx-webengine

I have a javafx application (jdk1.8.0_72) with an embedded webView component.

I have this svg, created by the inkscape tool:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg
   xmlns:osb="http://www.openswatchbook.org/uri/2009/osb"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   width="1920"
   height="600"
   viewBox="0 0 1920 600"
   sodipodi:docname="prova_link.svg">
  <metadata
     id="metadata8">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs6">
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient4288"
       osb:paint="solid">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#ff0000;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop4290" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       id="linearGradient4210">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#00ff00;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop4212" />
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#00ff00;stop-opacity:0;"
         offset="1"
         id="stop4214" />
    </linearGradient>
    <inkscape:perspective
       sodipodi:type="inkscape:persp3d"
       inkscape:vp_x="78.642594 : 273.36913 : 1"
       inkscape:vp_y="0 : 967.24275 : 0"
       inkscape:vp_z="837.94953 : 273.36913 : 1"
       inkscape:persp3d-origin="458.29604 : 176.64486 : 1"
       id="perspective4153" />
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient4210"
       id="linearGradient4216"
       x1="166.32027"
       y1="80.578522"
       x2="526.18355"
       y2="80.578522"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1018"
     id="namedview4"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.80666667"
     inkscape:cx="67.403168"
     inkscape:cy="460.14918"
     inkscape:window-x="1358"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg2" />
  <path
     sodipodi:type="star"
     style="opacity:1;fill:#fa0000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:82.125;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="path4143"
     sodipodi:sides="5"
     sodipodi:cx="75.619835"
     sodipodi:cy="203.30579"
     sodipodi:r1="50.034138"
     sodipodi:r2="31.917227"
     sodipodi:arg1="0.7328151"
     sodipodi:arg2="1.3611336"
     inkscape:flatsided="false"
     inkscape:rounded="0"
     inkscape:randomized="0"
     d="M 112.80992,236.77686 82.262768,234.52406 55.27932,249.01879 47.982269,219.27057 25.858623,198.0869 51.895946,181.95429 65.20623,154.36734 l 23.389002,19.77771 30.349848,4.134 -11.58212,28.35591 z"
     inkscape:transform-center-x="3.2179809"
     inkscape:transform-center-y="-1.6127244"
     onclick="javascript:alert(&quot;HELLO&quot;);" />
  <rect
     style="opacity:1;fill:#de8787;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:82.125;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="rect4161"
     width="92.975204"
     height="50.826447"
     x="226.8595"
     y="74.380165" />
  <rect
     style="opacity:1;fill:#de8787;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:82.125;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="rect4163"
     width="140.08264"
     height="90.495865"
     x="388.01654"
     y="259.09091" />
  <path
     style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 296.29601,125.20661 417.1976,259.09091"
     id="path4165"
     inkscape:connector-type="polyline"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="100"
     inkscape:connection-start="#rect4161"
     inkscape:connection-end="#rect4163"
     onclick="javascript:alert(&quot;HELLO&quot;);" />
</svg>
```

The path with id "path4143" represents a "star";

The path with id "path4165" represents a "link" created by use of "connector utility";

Loading this svg on chrome, explorer and firefox, the onclick event is correctly triggered on the two svg elements.

Loading the same svg on the webEngine component on the javafx application, the onclick event on the "link" is not triggered.

It seems to be a bug on the javafx webEngine. 
Someone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: maybe it only registers clicks on fills and not strokes. It should work on either of course

Comment: I try to add the "Z command" to the path (close-path), and also to add a #000000 fill on the style attribute, but nothing.

Comment: I try to add the "Z command" to the path (close-path), and also to add a "#000000 fill" on the style attribute, but nothing. When i add some negative values to the "M command", the click is registered only on a part of the shape. The shape is obviously changed and this is not good for me.

Comment: Draw a rectangular shape such that the fill of that matches the stroke of the line you currently have.